# Benchmarking Memcached Server

Tags: memcached, benchmarking

I am trying to benchmark a memcached server. The results produced for TCP traffic are in terms of number of requests, number of hits, number of misses, number of gets, number of sets, delay time, etc. I am confused about how to produce throughput measure from it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest doing a lot of experiments at different loads, and drawing a graph of response time vs. requests-per-second.

Typically you will get a graph that looks like the one at the top of [this paper by Hart et al](https://www.facebook.com/download/170166286471212/hart12-modeling.pdf) which has an obvious "knee" which shows that if you apply too much load the response time suddenly gets much worse.

You could consider the requests-per-second of this knee to be throughput of your memcached system.